# Is it natural to say "You made your mom bleed", "You made your mom bleeding", "… mom being bleeding" or "…mom have bled"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, phrase-usage, phrase-choice

Mom was holding a glass bowl feeding son when he knocked it away, the bowl broke and a fragment of the glass cut her finger.

**Is it natural to say:**

- "*You made your mom bleed*" ( because we say "**make somebody do something**")
- "*You made your mom bleeding*" ("**bleeding**" could be an adjective and we have the structure "**make somebody + adjective**")
- "*You made your mom be bleeding*" (we can apply "**make somebody do something**" with the verb "**be adjective**")
- "*You made your mom have bled*" (we can apply "**make somebody do something**" with the verb "**have + PP**")

Answer (score 1):

> "You made your mom bleed" ( because we say "make somebody do something")

This is the only one that sounds natural to me.

> “You made your mom bleeding" ("bleeding" could be an adjective and we have the structure "make somebody + adjective")
>
> “You made your mom be bleeding" (we can apply "make somebody do something" with the verb "be adjective")

These constructs (and many others) do not work with adjectives that look like (-ing or -ed) verbs.

> You made your mom have bled" (we can apply "make somebody do something" with the verb "have + PP")

“have + -ing” is a verb tense rather than an adjective, and not the correct one for what you are trying to say.